# Browser doesn't send the cookie from domain with www after redirect

Tags: authentication, nginx, redirect, cookies, http-status-code-301

I have a staging version for my website which is `beta.example.com`. I recently added cookies authentication with the following setting:

```js
response.cookie(tokenName, token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + (tokenExpirationSec * 1000))
})
```

**In staging authentication works.**

When I deployed the code to production the cookie was successfully set (via `Set-Cookie` header) but was not sent to the server in server-side requests. So when I would refresh the logged in state would disappear but would be preserved in client-side requests.

It is worth noting that there's a 301 redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com`. Also the `host` header was `www.example.com` in production.

I eventually solved the issue by adding `domain` parameter when setting the cookie as follows:

```js
response.cookie(tokenName, token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + (tokenExpirationSec * 1000)),
  domain: '.example.com'
})
```

However I don't completely understand the source of the problem. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

> Domain specifies allowed hosts to receive the cookie. If unspecified, it defaults to the host of the current document location, excluding subdomains. If Domain is specified, then subdomains are always included.

So when I was in staging with `beta.example.com` without explicitly setting `domain` the implicit `domain` would be `example.com` according to MDN and `beta.example.com` would be excluded. But authentication did work in staging!

But I have the same situation in production with `www.example.com` so why doesn't it work in production?

This is the nginx config which does the redirect:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;

    server_name beta.example.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_pass.inc;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_pass.inc;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are misinterpreting the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).

> If unspecified, it defaults to the host of the current document location, **excluding subdomains**.

Meaning if you are on `beta.example.com` then `Domain` will be set to the value `beta.example.com`. This will **exclude** the cookie from other subdomains.

You must explicitly set `Domain` if you would like to use the cookie on all subdomains.